# html - page is not returning from one file to home page

Tags: html

**about.html**

**about/about.html**

`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My About Page</title>
</head>
<body>


    <h1>About me</h1>
    <p>bla bla</p>
        <p><a href="../dayseven.html">Back to Home</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

`**dayseven.html**`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Day Seven</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Visit me at <a href="about/about.html">my website</a></p>

</body>
</html>
```

`
when i click on back home link in **about.html** file. It does't return on home page(dayseven.html), it shows file not found message and

url of page not found page is
 http://localhost/practice_project4/about/dayseven.html

Comment: Where are all these files located on your file system?

Comment: in c drive, in www folder

Answer (score 0):

If you want `dayseven.html` to be your home page, you have to rename it to `index.html`.  `index.html` is the default homepage file name on most systems.  Alternatively, you could change the link in `about.html` to point to `../dayseven.html` instead, but this would leave you without a homepage.

Also, your link does not work.  You cannot post links to services on your local machine without a special setup, and especially not with a `localhost` URL.